# error: too few arguments to function

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and in a college course learning it, we have just started functions and this is my first lab dealing with them. I keep getting this error for each case in my switch statement and I am not to sure how to correct it.

> error: too few arguments to function 'void addFraction(int, int, int, int)'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void clearScreen();
void printMenu();
void getFraction(int&, int&);
void addFraction(int, int, int, int);
void subFraction(int, int, int, int);
void mulFraction(int, int, int, int);
void divFraction(int, int, int, int);
//void reducFraction(int &, int &);

int main()
{
    clearScreen();
    printMenu();
    return 0;
}

//Function clears the screen
void clearScreen()
{
    cout << string(50, '\n');
}

//Function prints a menu to the screen
void printMenu()
{
    int menu;

    cout << "Fraction Calculator\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "1. Add Fraction\n";
    cout << "2. Subtract Fraction\n";
    cout << "3. Multiply Fraction\n";
    cout << "4. Divide Fraction\n";
    cout << "5. Quit\n";
    cout << ":";
    cin >> menu;

    //Switch statement that drive the menu
    switch (menu)
    {
        case '1':   addFraction();
                    break;
        case '2':   subFraction();
                    break;
        case '3':   mulFraction();
                    break;
        case '4':   divFraction();
                    break;
        case '5':   exit(0);
                    break;
        default:    {
                     cout << endl << "Invalid choice\n" << endl;
                     printMenu();
                    }
    }

}

void addFraction(int f1n, int f1d, int f2n, int f2d)
{
    clearScreen();
    getFraction(f1n, f1d);
    getFraction(f2n, f2d);
    int fan, fad;
    fan = (f1n * f2d) + (f2n * f1d);
    fad = (f1d * f2d);
    //reducFraction();
    cout << fan << endl << "---" << endl << fad;
}

void subFraction(int f1n, int f1d, int f2n, int f2d)
{
    clearScreen();
    getFraction(f1n, f1d);
    getFraction(f2n, f2d);
    int fan, fad;
    fan = (f1n * f2d) - (f2n * f1d);
    fad = (f1d * f2d);
    //reducFraction();
    cout << fan << endl << "---" << endl << fad;
}

void mulFraction(int f1n, int f1d, int f2n, int f2d)
{
    clearScreen();
    getFraction(f1n, f1d);
    getFraction(f2n, f2d);
    int fan, fad;
    fan = (f1n * f2n);
    fad = (f1d * f2d);
    //reducFraction();
    cout << fan << endl << "---" << endl << fad;
}

void divFraction(int f1n, int f1d, int f2n, int f2d)
{
    clearScreen();
    getFraction(f1n, f1d);
    getFraction(f2n, f2d);
    int fan, fad;
    fan = (f1n * f2d);
    fad = (f2n * f1d);
    //reducFraction();
    cout << fan << endl << "---" << endl << fad;
}

void getFraction(int& numerator, int& denominator)
{
   cout << "Please enter a numerator: ";
   cin >> numerator;

   cout << "Please enter a denominator: ";
   cin >> denominator;

   while(denominator == 0)
   {
      cout << "Invalid denominator! Enter a new one: ";
      cin >> denominator;
   }
    clearScreen();
}
```

Comment: You are calling all functions without giving them any numbers to work on

Comment: In your switch statement you try to call the function without specifying the four arguments the function expects: i.e. you just call `addFraction();`. You'll need to get some values to pass as arguments... perhaps from the keyboard/`std::cin`, or hardcode something to start with....

Comment: could i do somthing like 'addFraction(0,0,0,0)' ?

Comment: And also the type of `menu` is `int`. So the case must be like `case 1:` not `case '1':`

Comment: @dbs1crew, `addFraction` should add the fractions. It should not clear the screen. It should not ask for input. It should not overwrite the arguments with input. It should not output anything. It's doing too much and its name is very misleading. If those other responsibilities were handled elsewhere, you would have sensible arguments to pass in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
case '1':   
    addFraction(1, 2, 3, 4);  
    break;
```

As mentioned in the comments under your code, you were calling the method with undeclared variables.

Answer (score 1):

You call the functions without any arguments

```
switch (menu)
{
    case '1':   addFraction();
                break;
    case '2':   subFraction();
                break;
    case '3':   mulFraction();
                break;
    case '4':   divFraction();
                break;
    case '5':   exit(0);
    //...
```

while the functions are declared as having multiple parameters

```
void addFraction(int, int, int, int);
void subFraction(int, int, int, int);
void mulFraction(int, int, int, int);
void divFraction(int, int, int, int);
```

You must supply required arguments for the functions' calls.

In fact you could declare the functions without parameters. For example

```
void addFraction()
{
    int f1n, f1d;
    int f2n, f2d;

    clearScreen();

    getFraction(f1n, f1d);
    getFraction(f2n, f2d);

    int fan, fad;

    fan = (f1n * f2d) + (f2n * f1d);
    fad = (f1d * f2d);

    //reducFraction();
    cout << fan << endl << "---" << endl << fad;
}
```

In the same way the other functions could be defined (and declared).

Comment: I will end up having to build on this code, so I will probably scrap a lot of this code and go with your suggestion. Thank you for input!

Comment: @dbs1crew Each your function asks for needed values itself. So there is no any need to declare them with parameters. It is enough to declare corresponding local variables in each function as I have sowed.

Answer (score 0):

Please input parameter value when calling a function.
Example:

```
case '1':   addFraction(1,2,3,4);
                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your addFraction function such that it takes four parameters.

```
void addFraction(int f1n, int f1d, int f2n, int f2d)
```

When you call it within your switch statement, you provide 0 arguments.

```
addFraction();
```

You must pass the function 4 arguments. For example, the following would be a valid call:

```
addFraction(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

All the functions you used has arguments to be passed, while when you are calling the functions from the switch case, you are not passing any arguments.

you will have to take in the fractions from the users first and then call the functions to operate on the fractions.

1. Ask the user for the fractions.
2. Use the fraction values into the function while calling.

case '1':
    addFraction(1, 2, 3, 4);
    break;